# Image is not moving in applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I want to move an Image ( here is rectangle ) in applet, applet draws it, but I wonder why the image is not moving? there is no compile error!

here is my code:

```
package game;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;



public class Gamer extends JApplet implements KeyListener
{
    private int x=50,y=50;


@Override
public void init(  )
{
    addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    switch( keyCode )
    {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        if( y>0 )  //when up key is pressed and the position of the player is not on the edge
        {
            y=y-19;
            repaint();
        }
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        if( y<171 ) //when down key is pressed and the position of the player is not on the edge
        {
            y=y+19;
            repaint();
        }
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        if( x>0 )
        {
            x=x-15;
            repaint();
        }
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        if( x<285 )
        {
            x=x+15;
            repaint();
        }
        break;
    }
}
@Override
public void paint( Graphics g )  //will draw the background and the character
{
    g.fillRect(x, y, 200, 200);

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

When I pressed my up/down/left/write arrow , the rectangle is not moving .
Please explain why ? T.I.A.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than `KeyListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your applet doesn't catch the `KeyEvent`, so your paint method does not get called.

In fact there is an issue when you want to add `KeyListener` to `JApplet` and it's not working.

Solution is to implement `KeyEventDispatcher` instead of `KeyListener`. Also I changed the size of your rectangle from 200 to 20 in order to be able to see the movements of the rectangle better:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Gamer extends JApplet implements KeyEventDispatcher {
    private int x = 50, y = 50;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) // will draw the background and the character
    {
        super.paint(g); // <- added to your code to clear the background
                        //         before re-painting the new square

        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        switch( keyCode )
        {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            if( y>0 )  //when up key is pressed and the position of the player is not on the edge
            {
                y=y-19;
                repaint();
            }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            if( y<171 ) //when down key is pressed and the position of the player is not on the edge
            {
                y=y+19;
                repaint();
            }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            if( x>0 )
            {
                x=x-15;
                repaint();
            }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            if( x<285 )
            {
                x=x+15;
                repaint();
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Your welcome. No, it is not mandatory to register the `KeyEventDispatcher` in the `init()` method. Since this is an applet, we are initializing all the components in `init` and in your example there wasn't any other suitable method for registering `KeyEventDispatcher`. Somehow in this sample it is mandatory ;-)